# How to Extract JSON From HTML Source Code Using Regex

Tags: python, html, json, regex, parsing

## Python Script

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301?defaultSkuId=30729125'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

# Save source code to file for testing
with open("sourcecode.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup))

# Regex pattern to capture JSON data within webpage source code
regex_pattern = r"{\"delivery\"*.*false*}}}"
```

**URL**: https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301?defaultSkuId=30729125

I'm trying to pull the **JSON** data embedded within the **source code** of the URL listed above using **Regex**.

I have manually pulled the source code from the URL listed and entered into [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/U6szh5/6) using the following **regex pattern**:

```
{\"delivery\"*.*false*}}}
```

The regex pattern appears to capture the desired JSON data needed.

### Issue

When I view the contents of the **soup variable** or saved file it appears to capture the HTML source code.
However, I do not know how to process regex to only capture the JSON data string needed to build my desired Python Dictionary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you try this: for content in soup.find_all(re.compile("__your_re_patter")):
    print(content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help you:

```
import re

url = 'https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301?defaultSkuId=30729125'

r = requests.get(url)
source_text = r.text
# Regex for extract info
json = re.findall('put your regex here', source_text)
```

To convert the returned list to json you can use:

```
import json
json_format = json.dumps(json)
```

Comment: Excellent ... The above pulls out the JSON portion from the source code as a LIST type.
How do I convert the list to a Dictionary. In the past I would use something like data = json.loads(json), but his throws an error.